# I recieve data from client but client cant read data from server only on localpc why?

Tags: tcp, server, client, message, tcpclient

I have a TCPClient and Server , everything works fine on my pc,if i send client to other pc (in same network) , client connect to server and can send data but client dont read data or server dont send , i have no errors nothing...What is the cause of this ?

i tried port forwording
changing from tcp to sockets
exactly same thing
adding firewall exception
removing antivirus

server

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;
using System.Net;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        public static Hashtable clientsList = new Hashtable();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TcpListener serverSocket = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any,3306);
            TcpClient clientSocket = default(TcpClient);
            int counter = 0;

            serverSocket.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("Chat Server Started ....");
            counter = 0;

                while ((true))
            {
                try
                {
                    counter += 1;
                    clientSocket = serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient();

                    byte[] bytesFrom = new byte[10025];
                    string dataFromClient = null;

                    NetworkStream networkStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
                    networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, (int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);
                    dataFromClient = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesFrom);
                    dataFromClient = dataFromClient.Substring(0, dataFromClient.IndexOf("$"));

                    clientsList.Add(dataFromClient, clientSocket);

                    broadcast(dataFromClient + " Joined ", dataFromClient, false);

                    Console.WriteLine(dataFromClient + " Joined chat room ");
                    handleClinet client = new handleClinet();
                    client.startClient(clientSocket, dataFromClient, clientsList);
                }
            catch { }
        }

            Console.ReadKey();
            clientSocket.Close();
            serverSocket.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("exit");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static void broadcast(string msg, string uName, bool flag)
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (DictionaryEntry Item in clientsList)
                {
                    TcpClient broadcastSocket;
                    broadcastSocket = (TcpClient)Item.Value;
                    NetworkStream broadcastStream = broadcastSocket.GetStream();
                    Byte[] broadcastBytes = null;

                    if (flag == true)
                    {
                        broadcastBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(uName + " says : " + msg);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        broadcastBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg);
                    }

                    broadcastStream.Write(broadcastBytes, 0, broadcastBytes.Length);
                    broadcastStream.Flush();
                }
            }
            catch { Console.ReadKey(); }
        }  //end broadcast function
    }//end Main class


    public class handleClinet
    {
        TcpClient clientSocket;
        string clNo;
        Hashtable clientsList;

        public void startClient(TcpClient inClientSocket, string clineNo, Hashtable cList)
        {
            this.clientSocket = inClientSocket;
            this.clNo = clineNo;
            this.clientsList = cList;
            Thread ctThread = new Thread(doChat);
            ctThread.Start();
        }

        private void doChat()
        {
            int requestCount = 0;
            byte[] bytesFrom = new byte[10025];
            string dataFromClient = null;
            Byte[] sendBytes = null;
            string serverResponse = null;
            string rCount = null;
            requestCount = 0;

            while ((true))
            {
                try
                {
                    requestCount = requestCount + 1;
                    NetworkStream networkStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
                    networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, (int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);
                    dataFromClient = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesFrom);
                    dataFromClient = dataFromClient.Substring(0, dataFromClient.IndexOf("$"));
                    if (dataFromClient == "closing")
                    {
                        clientsList.Remove(clNo);
                        Program.broadcast("Sa deconectat", clNo, true);
                        break;
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("From client - " + clNo + " : " + dataFromClient);
                    rCount = Convert.ToString(requestCount);

                    Program.broadcast(dataFromClient, clNo, true);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Opsy");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }
            }//end while
        }//end doChat
    } //end class handleClinet
}//end namespace
```

I have no erros even if i remove try catch, i removed them from server and client and no errors...

Answer (score 0):

Just took a quick look so not sure if this is the problem but you need to tell the program specific IP and ports to connect to when you're not testing on your own local system. You shouldn't need to worry about port forwarding as long as you are on the same subnet, but you should let the client know and server know what ports and addresses you want to use.